# Insert into relation table with returning

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables: clients, items and client_has_item.

```
CREATE TABLE clients (id_c serial primary key, name text);

CREATE TABLE items (id_i serial primary key, name text);

CREATE TABLE client_has_item 
  (id_c int references clients (id_c),
  id_i int references items (id_i));


INSERT INTO clients (name) values ('client a'), ('client b');
INSERT INTO items (name) values ('item a'), ('item a');
```

Note that a client can have several items, an item can be owned by several clients and names are not unique.

If I want to insert some items for one client (1, 'client a') it is easy:

```
WITH inserted_items as (
   INSERT INTO items (name) values ('item a'), ('item b')
   RETURNING id_i
)
INSERT INTO client_has_item (id_c, id_i) select 1, id_i from inserted_items
```

My question is how to do this for several clients. Ideally I would do:

```
 WITH inserted_items as (
   INSERT INTO items (name) SELECT new_items.item_name from (values (1, 'item a'), (2, 'item b')) new_items (id_client, item_name)
   RETURNING items.id_i, new_items.id_client
)
INSERT INTO client_has_item (id_c, id_i) select id_client, id_i from inserted_items
```

But I get the following error:

```
RETURNING items.id_i, new_items.id_client

********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new_items"
```

What would be the best alternative? Of course I could do a loop, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Are you asking about alternative query or alternative schema? Because this one seems inefficient to me. Why even keep separate table called "items" if you are inserting each item into both tables when you want to assign it to client? Are those items gonna be assigned to other clients as well? If they will, then certainly not with this SQL or you will get duplicates. So why not simply use the same procedure for first and any follow up items assignments? It will be a mess to maintain if you do things like that.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński yes, items can be assigned to several clients. Indeed they are not assigned for this particular query, but they could be with this schema. In that case it is clear that the returning couldn't be possibly adapted.

Comment: `INSERT INTO items (name) values ('item a'), ('item a');` this is one item or 2 different ones with the same name?

Comment: Two items with same name

Comment: So it looks to me like you have 1=1 relation between `client_has_item` and `items`. What benefit is there to having separate `items` table instead of adding `name` column to `client_has_item`?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński, an item can be owned by several clients. Not in the particular case, but the model is ready and it is possible in other cases.